# PhpStorm "Let definition are not supported by current JavaScript version"

Tags: javascript, phpstorm

I am trying to be a good little programmer and use the new tools available for coding JavaScript. Therefore I'm trying to use `let` instead of `var` to isolate variables.

This works fine in my browser however PhpStorm sees it as an error and when I hover above it gives me:

> Let definition are not supported by current JavaScript version

So my question is how do I upgrade the current JavaScript version?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Go to

**Settings / Languages & Frameworks / JavaScript**

(it may be **Preferences / Languages & Frameworks / JavaScript** on some OSes)

...and set the "JavaScript language version" to "ECMAScript 6" (or, if they've updated to reflect current naming, "ECMAScript 2015" — or "ECMAScript 2016" or later if you're coding to a newer spec):

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The setting is found in `File -> Settings -> Language & Frameworks -> Javascript` and the option should be on the left, a dropdown box next to "JavaScript Language Version"