# WebStorm “Let definition are not supported by current JavaScript version”

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I am trying to use new tools available for coding in JavaScript. I've seen the post [PhpStorm "Let definition are not supported by current JavaScript version"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35772101/phpstorm-let-definition-are-not-supported-by-current-javascript-version). I've tried as suggested over there, but do not work.

When I hover over the `export`

> Export declarations are not supported by current JavaScript version

When I hover over the `yield`

> Generators are not supported by current JavaScript version

and hovering over the `let`

> Let definition are not supported by current JavaScript version

So the question is how to upgrade the JavaScript version?

Comment: Why doesn't that solution work for you? Is the UI between these two pieces of software so different that you cannot access those menus?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

It can be set up like in the following image:

[image]

**Flow:** File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Javascript

Comment: Works for IntelliJ IDEA as well

Comment: I've got this setting exactly like this and still having these messages and red underlines - why?

Comment: @Vladyn Had to restart, then it worked.

Comment: It took about 1 min for me to have IntelliJ IDEA remove the red underline... I guess it was reparsing my project?

Comment: PhpStorm 2017.3.3 solution for above issue: [link](http://prntscr.com/lw28f0)

Comment: Worked as a charm

Answer (score 16):

Make sure you restart your IDE after changing the JS language version to ECMAScript 6.

Comment: This worked for me on WebStorm v2017.3

Comment: I didn't need to restart but I'm actually using IntelliJIDEA

Comment: I didn't have to restart either, and I am indeed using the WebStorm IDE.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set your JavaScript version in the IDE. This can be accessed on Windows with ctrl + alt + s. You need at least ECMA Script 6 to use `let`.

Answer (score 2):

As others suggested, setting the language version does fix this:

`File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Javascript`

**However**, that was not enough in my case. If you're experiencing these errors in a project that is nested within another project you must apply the JS language settings to the **parent project** as well.

In my case, it was a client-side React app nested inside a larger Java-based web-portal (Working with IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, which uses the same settings flow). I am adding this answer to the discussion in the hope that it can help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the settings for using this keyword

Go to File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Javascript (**Select ECMA Script 6**)